# How do I get the client's IP address from within a Perl Frontier-RPC call?

Tags: perl, xml-rpc

I'm trying to get my Perl Frontier XML-RPC daemon to know about the IP address of the caller.  I have to say I'm a newbie at Perl, so maybe this is obvious. I'm aware that [Frontier::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Frontier-Daemon) inherits from [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO), which has a `peeraddr()` method, but that doesn't help me when the daemon doesn't pass in its own instance to XML-RPC method calls.

Here's what my code looks like, roughly:

```
    my $server = Frontier::Daemon->new(
        methods => {
                diff => \&diff,
        },
        LocalPort => 8080,
        ReuseAddr => 1,
    );
```

And then later on down below:

```
sub diff {
    return $_[0] - $_[1];
}
```

How do I get the caller's IP address from within 'diff'?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this using Frontier's server class. By the time the local procedure/method is called, you don't have any handle on the actual socket connection itself.

As it happens, being able to access this information is a recent feature I added to the server class in my [RPC::XML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RPC-XML/) package. See the "[How Methods Are Called](http://search.cpan.org/dist/RPC-XML/lib/RPC/XML/Server.pm#How_Methods_Are_Called)" section in the docs for the server class.

Answer (score 0):

I run both Frontier::Daemon and Frontier::RPC2 (under Apache).  I do not know how to grab the client IP when using Frontier::Daemon, but if you use Frontier::RPC2 then the Apache environment variable $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} will contain the client's IP address.